# firebase authentication with redirect

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the `JS SDK` in a single page app. I am using the Google authentication with redirect but I can't get it to work. I have two flows:

First, User presses Login button I then call

```
ref.authWithOAuthRedirect("google", reject, {scope: 'email'});
```

I am redirected to google.com, finish the authentication, redirect back to my app with a query parameter `__firebase_request_key`. But then nothing... both `ref.getAuth()` and `ref.onAuth(function(authData){}) return authData == null`

Second, App starts if a user is already logged in I would like to get the token and call `ref.authWithCustomToken(...)` without redirect or any action needed from the user

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a popup instead of a redirect. Which has helped me in the past